# How to transfer data from one table to another randomly

Tags: sql, postgresql, random

Is it possible to put random values from `table1.column1` (5rows) into `table2.column2` (17 rows)?

What's more: `column2` in `table2` was added using alter table, so I have specific rows with ID and missing data only in that one added column.

example
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40PVU.jpg)

Comment: Can you add an example in your question? As written, it does not make much sense and it risks being closed.

Comment: What @Alexei said. What happens when you try it? things like non-null columns and columns with default values would make a difference here.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557